# restore a site collection to another web application on another farm

Tags: 2010, restore

We have an intranet that comprises of a single site collection and i want to restore a sql backup of this site collection to our staging environment so i can do some development against a couple of existing list.

im really not sure how to do this Can anyone give me some advice on the best way and what the potential problems will be

Answer (score 1):

- Restore database on SQL Server with any name
- [Attach databases and upgrade to SharePoint Foundation 2010](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc287634%28v=office.14%29.aspx), use any of the given method

In short, [Mount-SPContentDatabase](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607581.aspx) powershell command should help

PS: If there are any custom solutions, you will need to deploy all WSPs otherwise you might get errors.. Plus if you want to use existing accounts you may need to Migrate user accounts using [Move-SPUser](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607729.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

you can also take backup of your site collection and restore to your new server.

Comment: That's exactly what he says in his question..

Comment: Richard Banks asking for only SQL backup but i suggest him to take backup of whole site collection using STSADM so everything in his site collection remain same with data

Comment: @RobertLindgren

Comment: It was not me who downvoted you, so I guess I was not alone in thinking that your answer did not contribute

Comment: site collection backup is not easiest way to move